# Vectorize a function - Invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I'm new to python. 
I found an interesting article about vectorization, so I started studying it.
While I am able to do this:

```
 def cost(a, b):
    "Return a-b if a>b, otherwise return a+b"
    if a > b:
        return a - b
    else:
        return a + b

cost_vector= np.vectorize(cost)
print(z([1,2,3],[3,4,5]))
```

> output: `[4 6 8]`

I cannot do this:

```
ww = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,2,3,4,5,6],[3,2,3,4,5,6],[4,2,3,4,5,6],[5,2,3,4,5,6],[6,2,3,4,5,6]]

def cost(ww, a, b):
    if a > b:
        return ww[a][b]
    else:
        return ww[b][a]

z = np.vectorize(cost)
print(z(ww, [1,2,3], [3,4,5]))
```

> output: `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

I can't figure out how to do this mapping to my array

Thanks

Comment: What article is this?  It seems to suggest `np.vectorize` without enough warnings and important details.

Comment: A `numpy` beginner should not be using `np.vectorize`.  It's a fall back method when the operation cannot be performed with the fast compiled `numpy` methods.  Learn the `numpy` basics first.  It isn't a speed tool, and has a number of features that give the naive user problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `np.vectorize()` is trying to decompose all arguments, including `ww`.
As per [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) you need to exclude it via the `exclude` parameter, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np


ww = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      [4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]


def cost(ww, a, b):
    if a > b:
        return ww[a][b]
    else:
        return ww[b][a]


v_cost = np.vectorize(cost, excluded={0})
print(v_cost(ww, [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]))
# [2 3 4]
```

---

Note that you can do this in NumPy without the need for a `np.vectorize()`-decorated function.
You just need to make sure that `ww` is a NumPy array and use [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) twice:

```
import numpy as np


ww = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      [4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]


def cost(ww, a, b):
    return np.array(ww)[np.where(a > b, a, b), np.where(a > b, b, a)]


print(cost(ww, [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]))
# [2 3 4]
```

Comment: Thank you norok2, this should np.where(a < b, b, a) right?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Instead of np.array(ww)[np.where(a > b, a, b), np.where(a > b, b, a)]
it should be :
np.array(ww)[np.where(a > b, a, b), np.where(a < b, b, a)]

Comment: The code seems correct the way it is. Note that once the last two arguments are `a, b` and the other time are `b, a`. With your modification you would get a different result.